# watching scope of controller from isolated scope in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a dropdown, on selecting a value my variable in controller is getting changed but watch in directive is not getting triggered

```
<select ng-model="storesid" ng-change="changeVal(storesid)" ng-options="store.name for store in stores">
                <option value="">
            </option>
                </select>
```

and a controller which uses this.

```
app.controller("segmentCtrl",function($scope,$rootScope,segmentService,lookupService){
    $scope.changeVal = function(item){
    $scope.timeSeries = item;
   }
})
```

and a directive

where I am watching the

```
.directive('timeseries1',function(){
return{
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
      val:'='
    },
    link:function(scope,element,attrs){
        scope.$watch('timeSeries',function(){ 

        })   
    }
}
})
<div ng-controller="segmentCtrl">
 <timeseries1 id="dualAxisAreaContainer4" val="timeSeries" ></timeseries1> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable is known as "val" in your directive scope. So watch that instead will do.